# Update Fix Version/s automatically when issue linked Fix Version/s got updated in JIRA

Tags: jira

I want to update the Fix version/s automatically when someone update the Fix Version/s in the linked issue.  For eg :- I have Issue A which is having Fix Version/s :- 2.1.2 and Issue B which is linked with Issue A with issue link type "is covered by". In Issue B Fix Version updates to 2.1.3 then system automatically update fix version in Issue A.

I have script runner plugin installed.  Do i need to use REST API or Listener or Trigger..what would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how fix version is intended to work...

Fix version is used to define in what code base your work is placed, i.e. what deployment package. This should not change based on related issues.

However, Jira is open to any way of working so if you want to do this then you probably can use the Automation feature to make that happen. I have not tried it, but it should be possible to trigger a change based on that relation.